# continuously save result in the same file from R

Tags: r, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I need to perform the same analysis for several countries.So, each time i get the result,I want to save results(FPR;TPR) of differet countries on the same file from R but it overwrites the result. How can I keep exporting the result on the same file without having to lose previous result.
Thank you for the help!

```
  Countries <- c("Brussel")
  FPR <- c(FPR.GL)
  TPR <- c(TPR.GL)
  glob <- data.frame(Countries, FPR, TPR)

  write.table(glob, file="result_glob.txt")
  glob <- read.table("result_glob.txt")
```

Comment: I think you need to use `append = TRUE` in the `write.table`  function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `append` argument. From `?write.table`

> append: logical. Only relevant if 'file' is a character string.  If
>             'TRUE', the output is appended to the file.  If 'FALSE', any
>             existing file of the name is destroyed.

So the first time you write to the file, use

```
write.table(glob, file="result_glob.txt)
```

Then subsequent writes, use

```
write.table(glob, file="result_glob.txt, col.names = FALSE)
```

to avoid adding the column names.

Comment: But that keeps adding column names to the outputfile, unsure if that's desired output for OP.

Comment: @Heroka Thanks. Updated answer.

Comment: tropicalbath if @csgillespie's answer is sufficient, please mark it accepted. Keeps others from answering your question.